# Help debugging: org-mode hangs on agenda tag search

Tags: org-mode

I'm still pretty new to emacs and org mode, and I would really appreciate some help debugging a weird issue I'm having. When I try to do an agenda search by tag (`C-c C-a m [some tag]`), emacs just hangs. I can exit the process with `C-g`, but the search never completes.

Also, if there are no matching tags, the search doesn't hang, but immediately returns an empty result.

OS: Debian 9, GNOME

Emacs 25.1.1 (but also happened with Emacs24)

Org: 9.2.1

Value of `org-agenda-files`

```
("~/Dropbox/org")
```

Output of debugger after `toggle-debug-on-quit`, try a search, and `C-g`

```
  org-scan-tags(agenda (lambda (todo tags-list level) (progn (setq org-cached-props nil) (or (and (member "project" tags-list))))) nil)
  byte-code("\306!\210\307!\203\310!\202\311\312\"\211\204'\313\314\"C\315\n\"\202Vr    q\210\316\317!\2046\311\320\"\210\212\214   \f=\203F
}\210\202H~\210\321\322#\315\n\"+\306\207" [file buffer rtn rtnall org-agenda-restrict org-agenda-restrict-begin org-check-agenda-file file-exists-p org-get-agenda-file-buffer error "No such file %s" format "ORG-AGENDA-ERROR: No such org-file %s" append derived-mode-p org-mode "Agenda file %s is not in Org mode" org-scan-tags agenda org-agenda-restrict-end matcher org--matcher-tags-todo-only] 5)
  byte-code("\203*  ;\203\306\307\n\206\203\310\202\311 #\202)\306\312\203'\310\202(\311\"\313  !\314\315   P!\210
@
A\316\317!\210\320\317!\210 5\321\3226D\323\324\3255FE7\326\325\327\"8\32598\211A8\242\211:\203p\330\331\215\210\202\\;\204\302\332\333!<r<q\210\334\216\335c\210\336e`S\337\340\341\342    PF#\210`=   \343\261\210\336=`S\337\344D#\210`=>\204\260\345\346!c\210\336=`S\337\340D#\210\347 +c\210\202\342;\350\232\204\342;;\203\334\351;\337\340#\343\261\210\202\342\352\353;\"\210\354e!\2109\203\364\3559\317\"\343\261\210eb\210>\204\377\356 \210\336ed\357\317\3606 D\3617\362?\257#\210\363 \210\364\211@\207" [org-agenda-sticky match org-keys todo-only org-agenda-buffer-name matcher format "*Org Agenda(%s:%s)*" "M" "m" "*Org Agenda(%s)*" org-make-tags-matcher org-agenda-prepare "TAGS " org-compile-prefix-format tags org-set-sorting-strategy org-tags-view quote if current-prefix-arg nil org-agenda-files ifmode nextfile (byte-code "\306!\210\307!\203\310!\202\311\312\"\211\204'\313\314\"C\315\n\"\202Vr  q\210\316\317!\2046\311\320\"\210\212\214   \f=\203F
}\210\202H~\210\321\322#\315\n\"+\306\207" [file buffer rtn rtnall org-agenda-restrict org-agenda-restrict-begin org-check-agenda-file file-exists-p org-get-agenda-file-buffer error "No such file %s" format "ORG-AGENDA-ERROR: No such org-file %s" append derived-mode-p org-mode "Agenda file %s is not in Org mode" org-scan-tags agenda org-agenda-restrict-end matcher org--matcher-tags-todo-only] 5) generate-new-buffer " *temp*" ((byte-code "\301!\203\n\302!\210\301\207" [temp-buffer buffer-name kill-buffer] 2)) "Headlines with TAGS match: " add-text-properties face org-agenda-structure short-heading "Match: " "\n" org-warning substitute-command-keys "Press \\<org-agenda-mode-map>`\\[universal-argument] \\[org-agenda-redo]' to search again\n" buffer-string "" propertize user-error "Invalid value for `org-agenda-overriding-header': %S" org-agenda-mark-header-line org-agenda-finalize-entries org-agenda-fit-window-to-buffer org-agenda-type org-last-args org-redo-cmd ...] 11)
  org-tags-view(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-tags-view nil)
  call-interactively(org-tags-view)
  byte-code("\306   \307    \232\203\310\202\n\311\306\312\313\"\"\314
\"p@\315\316 !A\306\211BC\306\211DE\306\211FGH\204ZI\204K\317\320\321\306#\210\306JK\306\211\223\210L\306\211\223\210\317\322\323\306#\210\317\322\324\306#\210pMN\204|\325!\211G@NGAOP\203\207\326\327N\"H\204\322O\203\322\317\320\321AC#\210O\330=\203\264pJK\331 \306\223\210L\332 \306\223\210\202\322O\333=\203\322\212pJ\334\335!\210K`\306\223\210L\336\335!\306\223\210)\337N\"\211B\203\340B89\204\356\341\340B8!\203\376\340B8D\342\343B8!E\344B8FP\203E;\203\326\345NE#\206\326\327N\"\317\322\323F#\210D\346=\2033\347F\350\"\202UD\351=\203B\347F\352\"\202UD\353=\203Q\347F\354\"\202UD\355=\203`\347F\356\"\202UD\357=\203o\347F\360\"\202UD\361=\203~\347F\362\"\202UD\363=\203\215\347F\364\"\202UD\365=\203\234\347F\366\"\202UD\367=\203\256\370 \210\347F\371\"\202UD\372=\203\300\370 \210\347F\373\"\202UD\374=\203\322\370 \210\347F\375\"\202U\341D!\203\341\347F\376\"\202U\377D!\203\362\347F\201T\"\202U\201U\201VD\"\202U\201WBA@B\211AA\262\"\202UN\201X\232\203#\f\201Y\303!\202UN\201Z\232\2036\201[\201\\!\202UN\201]\232\203I\201[\201^!\202UN\201_\232\203o\201^Q\206]\201`QRQS\201[R!+\202UN\201a\232\203\202\201[\201b!\202UN\201c\232\203\250\201bQ\206\226\201dQRQS\201[R!+\202UN\201e\232\203\273\201[\201f!\202UN\201g\232\203\341\201fQ\206\317\201hQRQS\201[R!+\202UN\201i\232\203\364\201[\201j!\202UN\201k\232\203\201f\306\201l\"\210\201m\201n\201o\335\211$\202UN\201p\232\203(\201[\201q!\202UN\201r\232\203;\201[\201s!\202UN\201t\232\203N\201Y\201u!\202U\201U\201v!.\207" [prefix-descriptions org-agenda-buffer-name org-agenda-window-setup org-agenda-custom-commands org-agenda-custom-commands-orig org-agenda-custom-commands-contexts nil buffer-name current-window delq mapcar #[(x) "A;\203\f    B\302\207A@;\203\207A@\204'@\303\211AA\262BB\207@\303ABB\207" [x prefix-descriptions nil ""] 4] org-contextualize-keys buffer-file-name buffer-base-buffer put org-agenda-files org-restrict org-agenda-redo-command org-lprops last-args org-agenda-get-restriction-and-command format "*Org Agenda(%s)*" region region-beginning region-end subtree org-back-to-heading t org-end-of-subtree assoc 2 functionp eval 3 4 "*Org Agenda(%s:%s)*" agenda org-let (org-agenda-list current-prefix-arg) agenda* (org-agenda-list current-prefix-arg nil nil t) alltodo (org-todo-list current-prefix-arg) search (org-search-view current-prefix-arg org-match nil) stuck (org-agenda-list-stuck-projects current-prefix-arg) tags ...] 6)
  org-agenda(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-agenda nil)
  call-interactively(org-agenda nil nil)
  command-execute(org-agenda)
```

**EDIT** I see this `"Agenda file %s is not in Org mode"` message, but the search for TODOs works fine, `C-c a t`, so my agenda files must be in Org mode, right??

And even with a super minimal org-mode file

```
* Test                                                              :project:
** TODO Fix emacs!
```

And limiting searches with `<`, gathering TODOs works, but the tag search hangs.

** end of edit **

I've been stuck on this for days. Any ideas? Is it a GNOME issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I had a similar problem, the "solution" was to use shorter names for tags. I think more than 25 confuses org-mode.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it yesterday through elimination. Here is a workaround. I struggled with the same problem for some months. 4 different computers, install and re-install, emacs25 & 26.  This is a problem with one or more of the files in the directory

> .emacs.d/elpa/org-9.2.1

Perhaps a more experienced person can say what those files are for (obviously Org-mode, but...). But I have simply renamed the directory and everything is working great. But my .emacs file is only 250 lines long (and 70 of that is simply capture templates) so I am not using org-mode to its fullest.

(Had the problem on Mint, Debian Mint, Ubuntu)

Comment: Accept your own answer when you're able to.

Comment: I am new from yesterday. What does it mean to accept my own answer? (Thanks)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem was fixed by updating to emacs26.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Have you found any bug reports that are relevant to this? Maybe this is a bug in `org-mode` that can be fixed by updating just `org-mode` itself.